# Правильный способ создания изменяемых массивов

Tags: массивы, objective-c

Есть несколько способов создания пустых изменяемых массивов:

```
1. NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
2. NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
3. NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Какая между ними разница? Где-то читал, что первый способ - не autoreleased, но имеет ли это значение, если включен механизм ARC? Какой способ лучше применять для ARC, и что значит в данном случае alloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове alloc, new, copy, mutableCopy мы владеем объектом, и, следовательно, ответственны за его освобождение в MRR (не ARC) среде. В ARC среде мы можем не волноваться за его освобождение.

Создавать объект рекомендуется всегда явным образом, объединяя два метода в одну строку: alloc - метод класса, выделяет необходимое количество памяти под объект, init - метод экземпляра, инициализирует эту память данными, возвращая нам готовый к использованию объект. Все остальные методы (new, array и т. д.) созданы для удобства и наглядности и все равно вызывают alloc и init, хоть вы этого и не видите.

Вышесказанное касается любых объектов, не только массивов.

Answer (score 2):

Вы все правильно читали, первый способ нужно релизить вручную, после введения ARC это уже не имеет значения. Третий способ насколько помню является полным синонимом первого, по крайней мере для стандартных классов